# AppBar with Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to program an AppBar. Unfortunately without success. Google's web apps served as a template. Google implements their web apps with full-size menu (and auto collapse to side menu + hamburger in mobile) and search box. Even hours of searching on the Internet did not produce any results. Who has
ever programmed such a AppBar and made its source code available?

I tried this code from the exxample. In this example the code is in the /src/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';      
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';      
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';      
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';                                 
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';      

class App extends Component {                                                                            
  render () {                                                                                            
    return (                                                                                             
      <MuiThemeProvider>                                                                                 
        <AppBar />                                                                                       
      </MuiThemeProvider>                                                                                
    );                                                                                                   
  };                                                                                                     
};                                                                                                       

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));                                               
registerServiceWorker();
```

This is the error messages:

```
bundle.js:37989 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `theme` is marked as required in `MuiThemeProvider`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in MuiThemeProvider (at index.js:10)
    in App (at index.js:17)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? please give some code sample.

Comment: Did you look at material-ui project? They have working AppBar with collapse behavior and hamburger as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWoPy3gnM7I) tutorial to recreate the App bar with Material UI in react.

**Updating post after error, comment by original poster:**

You can pass theme props by following the pattern below:

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

...

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    textColor: cyan500,
  },
  appBar: {
    height: 50,
  },
});

...

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
  <AppBar title="My AppBar" />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

You can find the complete code from [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes).